# Json data not displayed because of a syntax error

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, web

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Florida Tempatations</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <section class = "header">
    <nav>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png"></a>
      <div class="nav-links">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ATTRACTIONS</a></li>
          <li><a href="">ABOUT US</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <div id="attractions-container"  style="text-align: center;"> </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  


    
  <script src="https://replit.com/public/js/replit-badge.js" theme="blue" defer></script> 
</body>

</html>
```

index.html^^

```
fetch('attractions.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => {
    const list = document.querySelector('attractions');
    data.forEach(attraction => {
      const item = document.createElement('li');
      item.innerHTML = `<h2>${attraction.name}</h2>
        <p>Location: ${attraction.location}</p>
        <p>Category: ${attraction.category}</p>`;
      list.appendChild(item);
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  });
```

script.js

```
{ "attractions":[
  {
    "name": "Walt Disney World",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
  {   
    "name": "Universal Studios Florida",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
   {    "name": "Kennedy Space Center",    "location": "Cape Canaveral",    "category": "Science and Technology"
   },
  {"name": "South Beach",    "location": "Miami",    "category": "Beach"
  },
   {    "name": "Everglades National Park",    "location": "Homestead",    "category": "National Park",
   }
  ]
}
```

attractions.json^^

```
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
}
.header{
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(4,9,30,0.7),rgba(4,9,30,0.7)), url('back.jpg');
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  position: relative;
}

nav{
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1% 2%;
}

nav img{
  text-align: right;
  flex: 1;
}

.nav-links ul li{
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav-links ul li a{
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-links ul li::after{
  content: '';
  width: 0%;
  height: 4px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background: #e7902c;
  transition: .25s;
}

.nav-links ul li:hover::after{
  width: 100%;
}
```

style.css^^

So basically I am trying to make this display on my website but I am not sure why it's not displaying. I tried my json fetch code and it works after I run some tests on it but I am not sure what is wrong with it because it's not displaying. I have a syntax error but I don't know where so I would appreciate if someone can help me with that. I am still learning my way around HTML CSS and JSON(This is my first time). Sorry if this is a silly question

Error:

> Error: Error: SyntaxError
> {}https://fd7ab24b-cc13-4b1d-9bf6-51305c5b96b1.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:74
> at t.formatMsg
> (https://fd7ab24b-cc13-4b1d-9bf6-51305c5b96b1.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:74:4990) at new e
> (https://fd7ab24b-cc13-4b1d-9bf6-51305c5b96b1.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:74:1632) at t.insertSync
> (https://fd7ab24b-cc13-4b1d-9bf6-51305c5b96b1.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:97:17121)
> at
> https://fd7ab24b-cc13-4b1d-9bf6-51305c5b96b1.id.repl.co/__replco/static/devtools/devtools.js:97:18724

Comment: Please read the tag descriptions before you use the tags. JSON: _"Before you ask a question, validate your JSON using a JSON validator such as JSONLint (https://jsonlint.com)."_ Your JSON data isn't valid.

Answer (score -2):

`"category": "National Park",` needs to be `"category": "National Park"` since it is the last item.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(`{ "attractions":[
  {
    "name": "Walt Disney World",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
  {   
    "name": "Universal Studios Florida",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
   {    "name": "Kennedy Space Center",    "location": "Cape Canaveral",    "category": "Science and Technology"
   },
  {"name": "South Beach",    "location": "Miami",    "category": "Beach"
  },
   {    "name": "Everglades National Park",    "location": "Homestead",    "category": "National Park"
   }
  ]
}`))
```

But with the comma at the end you get an error:

```js
console.log(JSON.parse(`{ "attractions":[
  {
    "name": "Walt Disney World",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
  {   
    "name": "Universal Studios Florida",    "location": "Orlando",    "category": "Theme Park"
  },
   {    "name": "Kennedy Space Center",    "location": "Cape Canaveral",    "category": "Science and Technology"
   },
  {"name": "South Beach",    "location": "Miami",    "category": "Beach"
  },
   {    "name": "Everglades National Park",    "location": "Homestead",    "category": "National Park",
   }
  ]
}`))
```

Comment: Please don't write an answer for a typo. Write a comment and vote to close or flag the question. Neither the question nor your answer are helpful for the community.

Comment: hey man I am sorry, I don't even know where I made an type

Comment: @dave I fixed what you said but the error still exists